# Is the memory address returned by malloc always interchangeable by a pointer to another type?

Tags: c, alignment, malloc

```
char arr[512] = {0};
int *ptr = (int *)arr; // WRONG
                       // A bus error can be caused by unaligned memory access

printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

On the other hand:

> The block that malloc gives you is guaranteed to be aligned so that it
>   can hold any type of data.

```
char *arr= malloc(512);
int *ptr = (int *)arr; // OK, arr is properly aligned for ptr

memset(arr, 0, 512);
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

Is this assumption correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard guarantees that malloc will return memory suitably aligned for the most stringent **fundamental type** (for example `uint64_t`). If you have more stringent requirements you have to use `aligned_alloc` or something like it.

> 7.22.3
>
> The pointer returned if the allocation succeeds is **suitably aligned so
>   that it may be assigned to a pointer to any type of object with a
>   fundamental alignment requirement** and then used to access such an
>   object or an array of such objects in the space allocated (until the
>   space is explicitly deallocated)

About `aligned_alloc`:

> ```
> void *aligned_alloc(size_t alignment, size_t size);
> ```
>
> The aligned_alloc function allocates space for an object whose
>   alignment is specified by alignment, whose size is specified by size,
>   and whose value is indeterminate.

---

Your code is correct as far as alignment is concerned. I don't particularly like the pointer conversion (`char *` to `int *`) but I think it should work fine.

Comment: Then `__uint128_t *ptr = (__uint128_t *)arr;`  is wrong, right?

Comment: @AlterMann If `__uint128_t` is not considered a fundamental type on that implementation AND it wants 16-byte alignment then yes.